# register user using json and local storage

Tags: reactjs, json, user-interface

I'm trying to create a webapp where a user can log in and register.
I have to store the user list locally, meaning no db is allowed, and I have a json file called "usersDB" instead.
I thought about creating the register using append or push but it doesn't seem to work, any idea how to add a new user?
my code:

```
let userFile = require ("./users.json");
const express = require("express");


const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3005;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/users",((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(userFile);
}))
app.get("/products",((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(productFile);
}))

app.post(`/register`, async (req, res, next) => {
    
    if(req.body.username.valueOf()===undefined||req.body.password.valueOf()===undefined ){
        res.err("undefined");
    }
    
    let id = genarateUuid();
    // createUser
    //add to db
    let user = {id:id,username:req.body.username,password:req.body.password,cart:[],purchases:[],login:[],sessions:[],isAdmin: false};
    userFile.append(user); //doesn't seem to work
    res.status(200).json(user);
    }
)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage Try with localstorage. You can just fill it with data like a map. The browser handles the rest. Remember, JS is not secure since everybody can read your code. You should handle user logins with a database and server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using node and express. You'll need to use `fs` to read/write to files (and I like to use `path` in combination with `fs` to build the file paths).

To write to a file (Assuming users.json contains an array of user objects):

```
const fs = require('fs');

app.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  // build user variable...

  // read current file contents
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'users.json');
  const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const data = JSON.parse(fileData);

  // append the new user
  data.push(user);

  // write the file back to users.json
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(data));

  res.status(200).json(user);
});
```

To read from that file:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {

  // read current file contents
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'users.json');
  const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const data = JSON.parse(fileData);

  res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

You could also refactor that code a bit more to avoid code repeat.
For instance, make a function called `getUsers`:

```
const getUsers = (filePath) => {
  const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const data = JSON.parse(fileData);

  return data;
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: how do you suggest I check if that user already exists from db? say we have a register that already exists and we want to put an error on that

Comment: also how would you also suggest checking the console when I run to see if it adds me a user?